# Fitnesse throw error convert from Integer to Double when using data from fitnesse table as a variable

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I'm started with fitnesse with link http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.DynamicDecisionTable 
But i toke a error when convert from Integer to Double when using data from fitnesse table as a variable. How to fixing it
[image]

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Slim. Are you using Java fixtures, or some other Slim version? Have you reported it as a bug (https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/issues)?

Answer (score 0):

i found reason of this error
I check Name of variable and catching that. Variable is not correct. 
i writen uppercase "C" in $totalCents therefore issues was resolved.
Thanks